# Android - New Window

Tags: android

So I want a user to input two strings (name and email, let's say) to add a contact. I'm really struggling with it.

I've created an 'addPerson' class where I wanted to set this up, so I call it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, addPerson.class);
startActivity(intent);
// ^ startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
```

It always crashes here, and I think the problem is when I enter my next addPerson class.

```
public class addPerson extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

I know this is something so simple but I've wasted hours of trying to research it, all the examples are either too simple or too complex. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the crash? If it throws an exception, what is it? Does it crash when you call `startActivity(intent)`, or when you call `startActivityForResult(intent, 1)`, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure and add your activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<activity android:name=".addPerson"></activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you add your second activity to the AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<activity android:name=".addPerson"
                android:label="Add Person"></activity>
```